# Who is file owner if the file is created using sudo command?

Tags: shell, permissions, sudo, io-redirection

I logged in using my username `ravbholua`:

ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ echo $LOGNAME
ravbholua

I create file named `a1`:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ echo>a1
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ ll a1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravbholua ravbholua 1 Oct  8 09:57 a1
```

As expected the above file has me (`ravbholua`) as owner.

Next I create a2 using sudo with `echo` command:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ sudo echo>a2
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ ll a2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravbholua ravbholua 1 Oct  8 09:57 a2
```

The owner is me only, i.e. `ravbholua`.

Now I create a3 using sudo again but with `vim` command:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ sudo vim a3
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ ll a3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10 Oct  8 09:57 a3
```

Oh! how come the owner changes now. It's not me but root.
Why such variation with `echo` and `vim`! 
It's a surprise that with *change of commands* how can the owner of the created file changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second example runs `echo` under `sudo`, but the *redirection* happens under the original shell.

```
sudo bash -c "echo > a4"
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one confirmation w.r.t. the example `sudo echo>a2`: the original shell 1st creates the file  and then sudo is run. So when the shell creates file, it makes the one owner of the file who is responsible for running the complete command `sudo echo>a2`

Comment: The order it happens in should be considered indeterminate. The result is the same though.

Comment: The redirection happens before the shell knows that it is running `sudo`, so the owner is the same as if you had just run `echo > a2`. You can get an error if the `sudo` user does not have write permission for `a2` (I run into this with an NFS mount that is read-only for `root`.)

Comment: @chepner Great! This is what I wanted - a confirmation and you did it perfectly. Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo` is just a command.

So for your first example:
`sudo echo>a2`

`sudo` is the command.   And while you have the redirection butted up against the echo, that doesn't mean anything.

For example:
`echo cat /etc/passwd > /tmp/foo`
You won't get the contents of /etc/passwd in /tmp/foo.  You'll just have `cat /etc/passwd`.  sudo is no different.  The echo part is just an argument to sudo.  sudo does use it to execute things, but the shell doesn't know that.

That's one of the ways where sudo access is very different from doing things as root.

For your example where you use `sudo vim a3` sudo runs `vim a3` for you as root.  And vim runs as root, so the file is owned by root.